# How can i add a parentNode with YUI3?

Tags: javascript, yui

i have : `<img src="myimg.png">`

How can i surround this with a link ? `<a href=""><img src="myimg.png"></a>`

So, i must create a parentNode.

I use YUI3 or native JS.

any idea ?

Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [wrap method](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_wrap)

```
var img = Y.one('img');
img.wrap('<a href="foo"></a>');
```

​
    ​

Comment: It says that my node has no wrap method oO